# Understanding Classes and OOP

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop

I have been trying to learn programming for a while with the book John Guttag's Introduction to Computation and Programming Using Python and I have reached chapter 8 which is "Classes and OPP". I am parapharasing him "A class should not be confused with instances of that class, just as an object of
type list should not be confused with the list type." What does he mean here with type list and list type ?

Comment: ``list`` and ``list()``?

Comment: The distinction isn't between "type list" and "list type", but rather between "object of type list" and "the list type". Given `fred = list()`, we say that `fred` is an object of type list. Python even makes this explicit, since we can check `type(fred) == list`. This does not mean that `fred` _is_ `list`. `list` is the type, `fred` is only an instance of that type.

Comment: Calling a type is how you instantiate an object of that type in Python, to expand MisterMiyagi comment.